# JsonConverter Excel VBA multiple results

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

A small question: i'm using JsonConverter from Github.
(https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas)

Code is working on most of the "GET" request.
Only when the same 'column' is accuring multiple times in the 'ResponseText' then it's not. (like "imei" in the example)

So I need a way to handle a long 'Responsetext' to fill multiple rows in an access db.

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)
MsgBox (Json("imei")) 'temp
```

Error 5: Invalid Procedure or Call Argument.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please post the JSON response you have the issues with.

Comment: Also, show some of the expected output as you mention this should feed into Access db so understanding the output format for the rows is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

used : https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
and named the module: 'mdl_JsonConverter'

```
 Set Json = mdl_JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)

         For Each item In Json
             input_1 = item("input_1")
             input_2 = item("input_2")
             'THEN DO SOMETHING WITH VALUES F.E. ADDING THEM IN A TABLE
         Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I can only provide a part of the answer, because I cannot recreate it, without the full JSON Response Text:

The response with mutliple values in JSON returns an Object of the type [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/collection-object). Hence you have to use a loop to iterate through all responses. Like this:

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)
For Each singleJsonItem In Json 
             'What object type is singleJsonItem? To find out, maybe use:
             'MsgBox singleJsonItem("imei")
Next singleJsonItem
```

You have to find out the object type of the collectionentries to extract the JSON Entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you responseText contains a searchRecords list then filter by searchRecords before for each

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
    
    For Each singleJsonItem In Json("searchRecords")
             'What object type is singleJsonItem? To find out, maybe use:
             Msgbox singleJsonItem("Name")
    Next singleJsonItem
```